# strange Javascript Float division result

Tags: javascript, math

```
var coeff='0.1';
var amount='12.2';

var res = Math.floor(parseFloat(amount) / parseFloat(coeff));

console.log(res);
```

Why the result of this is `121` (I was expecting `122`)?

**EDIT**: my question was ambiguous: no trouble with the `floor` function. I was just wondering why 12.2 / 0.1 is not equal to 122.

Comment: what does `console.log(parseFloat(amount) / parseFloat(coeff))` show?

Comment: @JaromandaX 121.99999999999999

Comment: Why use strings and parsing in the first place?

Comment: Because in my project I get these values from string (I init them as strings to make this question simpler).

Comment: @DavidD. hint: check the docs on exactly what `Math.floor()` does, then look at the console result jaromanda X clued you to

Comment: floor(121.9) is 121, floor is not a round-up/round-down function, it is a "take everything after the decimal away" function.

Comment: @JaredSmith I saw this.. the question is more why `console.log(parseFloat(amount) / parseFloat(coeff))` is 121.99999 instead of 122.0

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript - it has to do with floating point precision and has been asked many times - your original code masked the fact

Comment: @RoyDictus : take a look my answer to JaredSmith please. I have no trouve with floor, but with the result of division.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for pointing to the right question!

Comment: Yeah, that IEEE 754 lack of floating point precision will bite you in a lot of languages besides javascript

Answer (score 0):

the result is 121.99999999999999

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

> The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

so it cuts off the .99999. you might want to use

```
Math.round(parseFloat(amount) / parseFloat(coeff));
```

instead

Comment: explain the 121.99999999 instead of 122.0 (12.2 / 0.1 is 122 after all)

Comment: @JaromandaX From what I understand, javascript has a weird usage of bytes in your system. Don't ask me why though

Comment: @Timberman, there's no weird usage of bytes in my system by javascript or anything else. 7 years ago, I was pointing out that the answer did not fully answer the question - sure, it's obvious that `Math.floor(121.99999)` is `121` - everyone knows that, but why would the result of `12.2/0.1` be 121.99999 in the first place